# Paypal RESTful API: Is there a method to store a "Paypal" payment like a credit card?

Tags: paypal

I'd like to store a Paypal transaction for a long term authorization (greater than 28 days) to be finally captured when an item ships. (That way, there's no risk as no money has exchanged hands at that point.) It's easy to do with credit cards by indefinitely storing the credit card via the vault and charging it when the time comes, but is there a method to indefinitely store a Paypal account to be charged when the time comes?

Right now, the only way I see that possible is through Preapproval in the Adaptive Payments API, but is there a method to do the same in the RESTful API? If not, is it planned? Is/will it be exactly like the current Preapproval API where it might fail because it uses the exact funding source or will it be more guaranteed? (I understand if a credit card is full, or user deletes their Paypal account, but that should be a very rare event.)

More Info: The full amount is known to the consumer in advance, the general timeframe is known to the consumer in advance but not the exact date, the event or item could be cancelled so authorizations could be voided (therefore no money ever exchanges hands), and the money will go directly to me and not in escrow or chained with any other Paypal account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is in the works. It would be more like a long term OAuth access-token than a vault id for credit cards - since it's a user's approval to charge their PayPal account in the future. I will try to find the exact release plan but AFAIK it's some time around July time frame.

Comment: Great, looking forward to it!

Comment: It got delayed due to other capabilities we released recently but it's close to completion - I believe the target is definitely Q4, just don't know the exact date.

Comment: I suppose it got delayed again, is there any update?

Comment: sorry guys - I no longer work at PayPal. But we did do a soft launch  ~Nov with Uber as the launch partner. You can attach your PayPal account as a payment method to your Uber account using OAuth tokens. But at the time I left (Dec'13) it was still under compliance and risk review to open it up to all developers through developer.paypal.com. I'm not sure of the status now but I would recommend contacting @PayPalDev on twitter.