# PayPal REST API and recurring payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm looking at the new PayPal REST API and the examples. Does it work as of today to make recurring payments? (a.k.a: subscriptions with recurring payments with billing cycle and the number of times the recurring payment is made.)

I cannot find this information in the documentation.

Thanks,

Comment: Please try this code for recurring Paypal payment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390065/implement-payum-laravel-recurring-payment/65305466#65305466

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PayPal REST API doesn't currently offer recurring payments, although the Classic APIs do offer this feature:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/use-cases/

Comment: any updates on this? its really useless to go with new REST API without such a basic option such as recurring payments

Comment: @ulkas PayPal REST API now supports Recurring Payments.

Comment: this answer needs to be updated. PayPal now supports Recurring payments. Also the link provided is broken

Answer (score 20):

PayPal REST API now officially support [Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements) (Billing Plans and Agreements)

Comment: I have successfully created a billing agreement having setup fees $50. And when I look into my facilitator account, the same $50 is added to my balance. But how do I get confirmation about this? Can I get any payment id or anything else like that from which I can confirm that the amount paid is from the particular customer.

Comment: Note that while the "billing plan" feature provides equivalent functionality for new recurring payments, it is a completely different implementation inside PayPal from the old-school "recurring payments" set up through the SOAP or NVP APIs. That means that existing recurring payments cannot be handled through the REST API, locking you into the old APIs if you have to continue supporting old recurring payment agreements.

Comment: @Vimalnath and viper  can you please let me guide me a little bit how can i achieve monthly payments using paypal rest api.
mean to ask what are the steps in genera to achieve this confused with the terms   Billing Plans and Agreements

Answer (score 4):

There are two options here for the REST API.

First you can store a credit card in the vault to make recurring payments against that card.

The second option is not yet released, but will involve a long term OAuth token, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890214/2386464).

Answer (score 1):

Try the Paypal REST API-> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/

After setting your account, you´ll get a secret key and client id, which you´ll use later on to make the call to the api.

Remeber to set the grant_type on the apiContext so you don´t get a 403.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-plan

Comment: I have successfully created a billing agreement having setup fees $50. And when I look into my facilitator account, the same $50 is added to my balance. But how do I get confirmation about this? Can I get any payment id or anything else like that from which I can confirm that the amount paid is from the particular customer.

Answer (score 1):

`Billing Plan and Agreement` APIs are also deprecated, we can use `Subscription API` instead,

Integration guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/