# Implement Payum/Laravel recurring payment

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payum

I have some issues trying to get this working, I've implemented the checkout express (or seems to be) successfully, but also my system needs subscription option, following this [example](http://payum.org/doc/0.13/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/recurring-payments-basics).

Now, my problem is that in Laravel you cannot simply put some random files, so I'm trying to do it in the correct way, sadly, there is no documentation of the classes and methods including on the library.

I've created some functions within controllers (I don't know if this the right way) the problem I'm facing now is trying to createRecurringPayment() to apply the desired amount of the recurring payment, is the final step I guess.

Thanks for yout help.

- app/controllers/PaypalController.php

  ```
  public function prepareExpressCheckout(){
      $storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject');
      $details = $storage->createModel();
      $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'USD';
      $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = 1.23;
      $storage->updateModel($details);
      $captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken('paypal_es', $details, 'payment_done');
      $details['RETURNURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
      $details['CANCELURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
      $storage->updateModel($details);
      return \Redirect::to($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
  }

  public function prepareSubscribe(){
      $storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject');
      $details = $storage->createModel();

      $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = 0;
      $details['L_BILLINGTYPE0'] = Api::BILLINGTYPE_RECURRING_PAYMENTS;
      $details['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] = "Suscripción por X meses";
      $details['NOSHIPPING'] = 1;

      $storage->updateModel($details);
      $captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken('paypal_es', $details, 'payment_done');
      $storage->updateModel($details);

      return \Redirect::to($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
  }

  public function createRecurringPayment(){
      $payum_token = Input::get('payum_token');
      $request = \App::make('request');
      $request->attributes->set('payum_token', $payum_token);
      $token = ($request);
      //$this->invalidate($token);

      $agreementStatus = new GetHumanStatus($token);
      $payment->execute($agreementStatus);

      if (!$agreementStatus->isSuccess()) {
          header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
          exit;
      }

      $agreementDetails = $agreementStatus->getModel();

      $storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject');

      $recurringPaymentDetails = $storage->createModel();
      $recurringPaymentDetails['TOKEN'] = $agreementDetails['TOKEN'];
      $recurringPaymentDetails['DESC'] = 'Subscribe to weather forecast for a week. It is 0.05$ per day.';
      $recurringPaymentDetails['EMAIL'] = $agreementDetails['EMAIL'];
      $recurringPaymentDetails['AMT'] = 0.05;
      $recurringPaymentDetails['CURRENCYCODE'] = 'USD';
      $recurringPaymentDetails['BILLINGFREQUENCY'] = 7;
      $recurringPaymentDetails['PROFILESTARTDATE'] = date(DATE_ATOM);
      $recurringPaymentDetails['BILLINGPERIOD'] = Api::BILLINGPERIOD_DAY;

      $payment->execute(new CreateRecurringPaymentProfile($recurringPaymentDetails));
      $payment->execute(new Sync($recurringPaymentDetails));

      $doneToken = $this->createToken('paypal_es', $recurringPaymentDetails, 'payment_done');

      return \Redirect::to($doneToken->getTargetUrl());
  }
  ```
- app/routes.php

  ```
      Route::get('/payment', array('as' => 'payment', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@payment'));
      Route::get('/payment/done', array('as' => 'payment_done', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@done'));
      Route::get('/payment/paypal/express-checkout/prepare', array('as' => 'paypal_es_prepare', 'uses' => 'PaypalController@prepareExpressCheckout'));
      Route::get('/payment/paypal/subscribe/prepare', array('as' => 'paypal_re_prepare', 'uses' => 'PaypalController@prepareSubscribe'));
      Route::get('/payment/paypal/subscribe/create', array('as' => 'payment_create', 'uses' => 'PaypalController@createRecurringPayment'));
  ```

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot simply put some random files" what errors are you getting ?

Comment: I mean, that in Laravel you have to put files in specific folders (models, controllers, etc.) I was trying to follow that structure with this plugin.

Comment: Apparently there are no examples for recurring payments. @maksim-kotlyar is on the development team i guess ?

Comment: There is an example for [plain php](http://payum.org/doc/0.13/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/recurring-payments-basics). it could be easily adopted for Laravel. No need for a special laravel tutorial.

Comment: You get any error ? In laravel you can add classes in directory( ex: Libraries) and access the functions using namespace( You have to autoload directory before using it).

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar, just found out that you are the developer of payum. I have a quick question. Is there any shopping cart package built for laravel that we could use that already has payum integrated?

Comment: @omerFarooq I am not aware of any. Sylius uses it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem. It is with the parameters we pass to the create recurring payment function. Here are functions for agreement and payment creation. It should work fine.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus;
use Payum\LaravelPackage\Controller\PayumController;
use Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Api;
use Payum\Core\Request\Sync;
use Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\CreateRecurringPaymentProfile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PayPalController extends PayumController {

    public function prepareSubscribeAgreement() {

        $storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject');

        $details = $storage->create();
        $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = 0;
        $details['L_BILLINGTYPE0'] = Api::BILLINGTYPE_RECURRING_PAYMENTS;
        $details['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] = "Weather subscription";
        //$details['NOSHIPPING'] = 1;
        $storage->update($details);

        $captureToken = $this->getPayum()->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken('paypal_ec', $details, 'paypal_subscribe');

        return \Redirect::to($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }

    public function createSubscribePayment(Request $request) {
        $request->attributes->set('payum_token', $request->input('payum_token'));

        $token = $this->getPayum()->getHttpRequestVerifier()->verify($request);
        $gateway = $this->getPayum()->getGateway($token->getGatewayName());

        $agreementStatus = new GetHumanStatus($token);
        $gateway->execute($agreementStatus);

        if (!$agreementStatus->isCaptured()) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
            exit;
        }

        $agreement = $agreementStatus->getModel();

        $storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject');

        $recurringPayment = $storage->create();
        $recurringPayment['TOKEN'] = $agreement['TOKEN'];
        $recurringPayment['PAYERID'] = $agreement['PAYERID'];
        $recurringPayment['PROFILESTARTDATE'] = date(DATE_ATOM);
        $recurringPayment['DESC'] = $agreement['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'];
        $recurringPayment['BILLINGPERIOD'] = Api::BILLINGPERIOD_DAY;
        $recurringPayment['BILLINGFREQUENCY'] = 7;
        $recurringPayment['AMT'] = 0.05;
        $recurringPayment['CURRENCYCODE'] = 'USD';
        $recurringPayment['COUNTRYCODE'] = 'US';
        $recurringPayment['MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS'] = 3;

        $gateway->execute(new CreateRecurringPaymentProfile($recurringPayment));
        $gateway->execute(new Sync($recurringPayment));

        $captureToken = $this->getPayum()->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken('paypal_ec', $recurringPayment, 'payment_done');

        return \Redirect::to($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }

    public function done(Request $request) {
        /** @var Request $request */
        //$request = \App::make('request');
        $request->attributes->set('payum_token', $request->input('payum_token'));

        $token = $this->getPayum()->getHttpRequestVerifier()->verify($request);
        $gateway = $this->getPayum()->getGateway($token->getGatewayName());

        $gateway->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));

        return \Response::json(array(
                    'status' => $status->getValue(),
                    'details' => iterator_to_array($status->getFirstModel())
        ));
    }

}
```

The routes:

```
Route::get('paypal/agreement', 'PayPalController@prepareSubscribeAgreement');
    Route::get('paypal/subscribe', [
        'as' => 'paypal_subscribe',
        'uses' => 'PayPalController@createSubscribePayment'
    ]);
    Route::get('paydone', [
        'as' => 'payment_done',
        'uses' => 'PayPalController@done'
    ]);
```

Simply open www.example.com/paypal/agreement and it should take you to PayPal

Comment: amer, thank you for sharing your code. me and many others are also facing lot of issues due to lack of documenation. If you have successfully integrated this package in laravel, then i would suggest u to please create a git repo and share a working paypal demo + ipn resolver. That will definitely make my day, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In my project I used the following library and it helped me alot:

https://github.com/amirduran/duranius-paypal-rest-api-php-library

Here are some features:

- Easy to install - Just one file
- Library is implemented as PHP class
- It supports Recurring Payments It supports ExpressCheckout payments
- All available PayPal API methods are wrapped in belonging methods
- Well documented

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Pay Pal REST API code.

```
        //Request Perms
        $cardtype = $request->cardtype;
        $account_number = $request->cardnumber;
        $expire_date =$request->expire_date;
        $cvv = $request->cvv;
        $plan_id =$request->plan_id;
        $amount = $request->amount;
        $userid = $request->user_id;
        $payment_type = $request->plan_type;
         
       //Genrate tokens
        $ch = curl_init();
        $clientId ='Your Client ID';
        $clientSecret= 'Your Secret ID';
        //you get Clientid and clientSecret  
           https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$clientSecret);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
        else
        {
            $json = json_decode($result);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
                              
        $product_id = '';
         //you can create payment plan this link 
           https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans

        if ($plan_id == 1) {
            $product_id = 'your plan id';
        }elseif ($plan_id == 2) {
            $product_id = 'your plan id'; 
        }
         
            $ch = curl_init();

                $payment_data = '{
                   "plan_id":"'.$product_id.'",
                   "start_time":"'.gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",strtotime("+1 day")).'",
                   "shipping_amount":{
                      "currency_code":"USD",
                      "value":"'.$amount.'"
                   },
                   "subscriber":{
                      "name":{
                         "given_name":"",
                         "surname":""
                      },
                      "email_address":"'.$users->email.'",
                      "shipping_address":{
                         "name":{
                            "full_name":""
                         },
                         "address":{
                            "address_line_1":"",
                            "address_line_2":"",
                            "admin_area_2":"",
                            "admin_area_1":"",
                            "postal_code":"",
                            "country_code":"US"
                         }
                      },
                      "payment_source":{
                         "card":{
                            "number":"'.$account_number.'",
                            "expiry":"'. $expiry_date.'",
                            "security_code":"'.$cvv.'",
                            "name":"",
                            "billing_address":{
                               "address_line_1":"",
                               "address_line_2":"",
                               "admin_area_1":"",
                               "admin_area_2":"",
                               "postal_code":"",
                               "country_code":"US"
                            }
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payment_data);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$json->access_token.'';
        $headers[] = 'Paypal-Request-Id: SUBSCRIPTION-'. rand() .'';
        $headers[] = 'Prefer: return=representation';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);    
        $payment_id = json_decode($result);
        $data =$headers[2];    
        $subid = substr($data, strpos($data, ":") + 2);

       //save data in database
        $payment = new Subscription(); 
        $payment->userid=$userid; 
        $payment->plan_id=$plan_id;    
        $payment->price=$amount;
        $payment->sub_id=$subid;
        $payment->transaction_id=$payment_id->id;
        $payment->payment_type='Paypal';  
        $payment->charge=$paypal_charge;
        $payment->plan_type=$plan_type;
        $payment->subscription_startdate= $subscription_startdate;
        $payment->subscription_enddate= $subscription_enddate;
        $payment->subscription_status= 'active';
        $payment->save();

        return response()->json(['status' => true,'message'=>'Payment has been successfully Done','data'=>$payment]);
```

It's working fine for me.